# How to use: $this->Auth->user('id') in a model? Cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, authentication, model, cakephp-3.0

I've been working on the skinny controller fat model way. Before, I used this in my controller:

```
$this
    ->find('all')
    ->contain(['Declarator'])
    ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')])
    ->order(['Declarations.created' => 'DESC']);
```

However, `$this->Auth->user('id')`, doesn't work in a model.

What other way is there to get the id from the authenticated user in a model?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What other way is there to get the id from the authenticated user in a model?

Simply pass it to a model method:

```
public function someModelMethod($userId, array $postData) {
    // Do something here, move your code from the controller here
    return $something;
}

public function someControllerAction() {
    $this->set('data', $this->Model->someModelMethod(
        $this->Auth->user('id'),
        $this->request->data
    );
}
```

Cake doesn't have a layer that would take the business logic so most of the time it's put in the model layer. Cake also doesn't use dependency injection so passing whole instances around like the auth object is sometimes cumbersome. Also I don't think the auth object itself should intersect with the model layer. We want to avoid tight coupling. To simplify this (also for testing) it is much easier to just pass the required values to the methods.

Comment: Passing the logged in user id from every controller that it is used in can be extremely cumbersome. I get that the separation of concerns is important, but logged in user id is an integral part of how the model layer functions in the business use case that the code base I am working on supports. It seems like there should be a better way of handling separation of concerns without this much overhead.

Comment: @space97 we have a pretty big app and there is no "overhead" just people being lazy sacrificying architecture and by this maintenance and TCO on the altar of convenience... If you want to go that wrong path, well, even then there are better solutions: Make the model(s) implement an interface like "UserSetterInterface" that requires a setUserId() method. In the AppController::initialize() check each model for that interface via instanceof and if this is true pass the id from the component calling this method.

Comment: @burzum I am not advocating for breaking the architecture. I am actually working to pull the use of $_SESSION out of tables that was put in be previous devs, to make the app stateless and architectural reasons and am trying to figure out the right way to go about this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @space97 I hope you're not using $_SESSION directly. If you're using some kind of abstraction, it shouldn't matter if the user was authenticated by a stateful or stateless mechanism, because at this point, the id or identity data should have been already resolved, no matter via session or token. Check this out, it's framework independent but easy to integrate into everything. :) https://github.com/phauthentic/authentication

Comment: @buzum Thanks, I assumed that the session abstraction was not work for stateless. That makes things a lot easier. The code uses $_SESSION, which I am attempting to move it away from in this process.

Answer (score 2):

Mayby it's not a good idea, but in cake's model You can get users id using `$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id']`

Or just `use Cake\Routing\Router;` at the top of your `Table` class and then, You can get access to session using:

```
Router::getRequest()->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id');
```

Comment: This would not work for stateless user authentications

Answer (score -4):

In CakePHP 2.x it's done as stated below. I'm quite sure that, even though it's not in the docs, it may be done the same way.

```php
// Use anywhere
AuthComponent::user('id')

// From inside a controller
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

**Source:** http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

**Docs for version 3.x:** http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

Comment: Please comment if you downvote. I know this should not be done in the model, but my post answers the question.

Comment: Components are used in controllers not models